# Say my name and I'm there

Tags: riddle

I'm given once and only once, but you can take me for months and months.

You wish you were able to keep me for longer, but try to hold me, I promise I'm stronger.

You can try to refuse me, to not let me in, but this one is deadly for you and your kin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upon review, I think the answer may be

> Breath

I'm given once and only once,

> We all only get one life

but you can take me for months and months.

> You can take breaths all the time

You wish you were able to keep me for longer

> Many of us wish we could breathe indefinitely

but try to hold me, I promise I'm stronger.

> It's very difficult to hold one's breath for too long.
>  Also as CiaPan points out in the comments, once you stop breathing you soon lose your consciousness and then breathing resumes.

You can try to refuse me, to not let me in, but this one is deadly for you and your kin

> Again, not breathing in can be deadly

Title

> Say "breath" and you make a breath.

Comment: That was also my idea. However, for 'I am stronger' I would add ROT13 Bapr lbh fgbc oernguvat lbh fbba ybfr lbhe pbafpvbhfarff naq gura oernguvat erfhzrf - it's stronger than our will.

Comment: @CiaPan that is a valid point, will add in with credit.